# SQLSRV Loaded correct in PHP (xampp) but sqlsrv_connect never returns results after upgrading

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, xampp, sqlsrv

I was using PHP 5.5 with the sqlsrv drivers, afther upgrading xampp I changed the corresponding drivers for PHP 5.6 and changed the php.ini file the configuration looks good as I get the extension loaded in the phpinfo, but now when I try to run any query, the web page keeps loading and never returns information, after some minutes the client ends with an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Should I change something else on the apache configuration?

[image]